# color assigned to email address not working for other account

Tags: javascript, email, colors

I need help with this function,

Each email have a color. The function work with my account (I write with the good color). BUT the function don't work with the other accounts (the writing color is not the good one, it's stay black). I don't understand why it's don't work. 
(all account authorize the function) What do you think?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ActiveRow = ActiveSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var ActiveCell = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (email == "a@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#ff0066");
  }

  if (email == "b@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#e36c09");
  }

if (email == "c@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#0928bf");
  }

  if (email == "d@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#9a26a2");
  }

if (email == "x@gmail.com"){
    ActiveCell.setFontColor("#9a26a2");}
  }
```

Comment: So it's not "x@gmail.com", but "a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com", etc? Do other users see your color?

Comment: Yes other user see my color. I change the email, the are all different